# Google Chrome, html toolbar - always on top problem

Tags: css, google-chrome, toolbar

I am working on a toolbar for Google Chrome as a part of extension. Let's say the toolbar is a simple rect described by the below css:

```
#top{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    z-index:9999999;
    height:40px;

}
```

I inject the toolbar which looks more less like:

```
<body>
    <div id="panel_left">
    ....
    </div>
    <div id="panel_right">
    ....
    </div>
</body>
```

And I inject it to the iframe by:

```
$("body").before('<iframe name="top" id="top" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
var top = document.getElementById("top");
top.src = chrome.extension.getURL("top.html");
```

The problem starts on some webpages because of their css that is able to cover my toolbar. I expect the toolbar to start from the very top of the website take 40px height and then to display the usual webpage content.

Have you got any ideas how to do it (or rather improve it, because it works on some webpages)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add :

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

Add this before insert you toolbar :

```
// Take down the webPage
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.marginTop = '39px'; 
// Or more if your toolbar is greater
```

Comment: Please, have a look at: http://www.emposha.com/ that is the example of the website that the toolbar still does not work properly... If you have any idea how to fix it, would be great!

Comment: Mine works on this web site, can you provide a screen of what appens ?

Comment: Yes, of course! I present a screen from the top of emposha.com for you. The red rect is exactly my toolbar, so you could have a good looking example of what happens:

http://www.biqueter.com/fail.png

Comment: Another website that hides my toolbar:
http://www.milonic.com/mfa/2005-January/iframe-hides-my-drop-down-menu.html

and if you would like to see the real example what happens:
biqueter.com/fail2.png

Comment: Hey, your fix, didn't fix the problem. Still. The problem is their top of the page is positioned as fixed one I presume.

Answer (score 0):

Just for all users looking for the same solution. It works:

```
body
{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position:relative;
}
```